# Which area of study should i look for?

Tags: education

First post here and i hope this is the correct forum to ask this. I'm currently on my 5th semester of Computer Engineering. 
I´m having some hard time deciding on what to specialize or what to do when i go out from university.

Some areas or subjects i'm interested are Mathematics, programming, also gpgpu computing and how gpu/cpu micro architectures are developed/works and how to relate the hardware or architecture to the software.

That's some subjects i'm really interested to have a career when i go out, but i don't have a clear idea how is called to work on some of those areas or what i should look for, i'm really confused on what to do later when i graduate.

I hope some of you could clarify me this and give me an idea on what to look for.

Thanks for reading and sorry again if this is not the correct forum to post this.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.se]! Unfortunately, your question is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. We prefer questions that have objectively correct answers that will be useful both to the asker and others who have the same question in the future. What is or is not a suitable topic for study, projects or research is very much a matter of opinion and depends crucially on the interests and skills of the person who will be doing the work and the support that will be available to them. This is a question that you should be asking your professors.